# Power BI - Placing a table in variable (while nested in an IF statement)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Trying to add a table to variable inside an IF statement. Followed by using that var in a FILTER:

```
  --Get the code from the columnheader:
        Var SelectedItem = SELECTEDVALUE(StockItems[Code])
        
    --Check if we are calculating the total column (If so add all selected items):
        Var ItemList = IF(SelectedItem = Blank(),
                            SELECTCOLUMNS(StockItems,"Code",[Code]),
                            SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(StockItems,StockItems[Code] =SelectedItem) ,"Code",[Code])
                        )



    --Part what goes wrong
        Var test = CALCULATE(
                                SUM(Transactions_Sales[SalesExcl]),
                                        FILTER(Transactions_Sales,
                                            Transactions_Sales[LineItemCode] in ItemList))
```

Error I am getting:
[image]

while this is not a problem:

```
-- Works because the If is gone and DAX see that the var is a list/table
    Var ItemList2 = 
                        SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(StockItems,StockItems[Code] =SelectedItem) ,"Code",[Code])

      Var test = CALCULATE(
                            SUM(Transactions_Sales[SalesExcl]),
                                    FILTER(Transactions_Sales,
                                        Transactions_Sales[LineItemCode] in ItemList2))
```

So by using the IF, it seems to lose the type of List (or it cannot resolve it?)
Is there a work around? A cast maybe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `IF` always returns a scalar. If you try to plug in a table it will convert a single row of that table if there is a single row, and give an error otherwise. Use an unconditional expression like `SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(StockItems, (StockItems[Code] = SelectedItem) OR (SelectedItem = BLANK())) ,"Code",[Code])` instead (disclaimer: not tested).

Comment: Thanks, I changed your code slightly: 

Var SelectedItemsList = SELECTCOLUMNS(FILTER(StockItems, IF(SelectedItem <> BLANK(), (StockItems[Code] = SelectedItem),1=1)),"Code",[Code])

This works!